# MuleSoft Anypoint RuntimeFabric CICD Process

Tags: mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-platform, anypoint-rtf

I have a question on mulesoft anypoint runtime fabric cicd process.

I believe its a 2 step process.

1. mvn clean deploy --> deploys to exchange
2. mvn clean deploy -DmuleDeploy -->deploys to rtf from exchange.

Suppose if i published an app to exchange with version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and deployed to RTF.

Then made some changes to the app and published again 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT and deployed to RTF.

Now if i want to go back to 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT version and deploy to RTF how can i do that  or is there any way to deploy directly to RTF by specifying the version ?

I tried to follow this article and though of this question https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev-guides/how-to-tutorials/install-runtime-fabric-ci-cd-with-jenkins-and-nexus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Exchange has all the versions deployed with the first step you can change the version in the POM before executing the second step to deploy to Runtime Fabric.

Comment: lets assume the flow is httpListener ->transform (version:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT) published to exchange and deployed to RTF.

later i made the change to flow added a logger in end. (version: 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT) published to exchange and deployed to RTF>

Now i want to deploy the older version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT --> you are just suggesting just by changing pom version it should deploy old one . is that correct ? but the flow will still have logger right ?

can you clarify this plz

Comment: That's what the article you shared implies: "Maven relies on the POM GAV (groupId, artifactId, version) coordinate to locate the jar in Exchange. 

You can run the second command multiple times to deploy from Exchange to Runtime Fabric. However, the first command should be run only once with the same GAV. We’ll discuss in detail why that is the case in the next section."

Comment: I did tried and just by changing the pom version its pulling the code from exchange and deploying it. It really doesnt look whats in the mule flows.